# React.js component syntax error (Unexpected token) that I cannot find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Hey everyone and thanks for helping!
While updating my ruby on rails app from rails v5.0 to 6.0, I've encountered an error with one of my react components and despite the fact I tried to fix it with many JS linters, I couldn't find any proper solution.

That's the output I get:

```
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (3:8)
  1 | class AvatarUploadInline extends React.Component {
  2 | 
> 3 |   state = { url: this.props.url };
    |         ^
  4 | 
  5 |   trigger = (event) => {
  6 |     event.preventDefault();
```

And this is the component itself:

```
class AvatarUploadInline extends React.Component {

  state = { url: this.props.url };

  trigger = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#artist_avatar").click();
  }

  showPreview = (changeEvent) => {
    changeEvent.preventDefault();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (fileReadEvent) => {
      this.setState({ url: fileReadEvent.target.result });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
  }

  render () {
    return <div className="m-form__upload-avatar">
      <input name="artist[avatar]" id="artist_avatar" type="file" onChange={this.showPreview} />
      <span id="avatar" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.url})` }} className="m-form__upload-avatar__image" />
      <span className="m-form__upload-avatar__icon" onClick={this.trigger} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: there seems to be problem with babel. can you share your .babelrc file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your .babelrc file to be able to use this syntax.
This ll solve your issues at other places as well like functions.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2016"],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described on React documentation, create a constructor and initialize your state there to avoid bugs.

Like this:

```
class AvatarUploadInline extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   url: props.url
  }
 }
 ...
}
```

You can read more about [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor).